# FTP access to NAS drive files/folders from Wordpress site

Tags: plugins, ftp, remote-login

I have a client who requires a file sharing solution. We've developed a Wordpress site for his surveying company. They produce very large scan/3d files for each client (think 10Gb - 50Gb) which some clients need access to download. These are stored locally on a NAS Raid system.

He'd like to be able to offer some clients a 'client remote login' on his WP website that, on entering their unique credentials, displays their client folder contents (from the NAS) in the browser and have their files/folder available for list/download.

We think we can provide access to the NAS via ftp protocol, so is there a WP plugin that provides an FTP client UI in the browser that we can use to connect to the NAS?

Or can anyone suggest a simpler/smarter solution to this conundrum?

Comment: For large file sizes like this it would be better to go with a Dropbox or similar type account. These are made specifically for file sharing and will allow them to share each file with only specific users. This is much safer than allowing FTP access even to a different system.

Comment: I'd consider a self-hosted nextcloud with access to an external storage. LDAP might be your best bet for a SSO solution here.